# How can I read out the NCTOPLC_AXIS_REF in TwinCAT using Ads.NET?

Tags: twincat

I'm trying to read out `NCTOPLC_AXIS_REF` from the PLC, but when I do a `client.ReadAny(handle)`, it raises `System.ExecutionEngineException`. I've tried playing around with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]` and `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]` in my struct, but so far without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the struct that works:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class NcToPlcAxisRef
{
    public uint StateDWord;
    public uint ErrorCode;
    public uint AxisState;
    public uint AxisModeConfirmation;
    public uint HomingState;
    public uint CoupleState;
    public uint SvbEntries;
    public uint SafEntries;
    public uint AxisId;
    public uint OpModeDWord;
    public double ActPos;
    public double ModuloActPos;
    public ushort ActiveControlLoopIndex;
    public ushort ControlLoopIndex;
    public int ModuloActTurns;
    public double ActVelo;
    public double PosDiff;
    public double SetPos;
    public double SetVelo;
    public double SetAcc;
    public double TargetPos;
    public double ModuloSetPos;
    public int ModuloSetTurns;
    public ushort CmdNo;
    public ushort CmdState;
    public double SetJerk;
    public double SetTorque;
    public double ActTorque;
    public uint NcToPlcRefState2Value;
    public uint NcToPlcRefState3Value2;
    public uint TouchProbeState;
    public uint TouchProbeCounter;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public byte[] CamCouplingStates = new byte[8];

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public ushort[] CamCouplingTableID = new ushort[8];
    public double ActTorqueDerivative;
    public double SetTorqueDerivative;
    public double AbsPhasingPos;
    public double TorqueOffset;
    public double ActPosWithoutPosCorrection;
    public double ActAcc;
    public uint DcTimeStamp;
}
```